# Ascii .txt file to array of bytes - C++

Tags: c++, file, binary, hex

How can I convert an ascii .txt file into an array of bytes in c++?
For example given this .txt file of XYZ Coordinates convert it to an array of bytes in floating point representation:

```
253.9999929 58.0428367 -21.3930063253
.9999929 59.0435773 -21.2499391255
...
```

converts to

```
bytes array[] = {
01000011,01111110,00000000,00000000,
01000010,01101000,00101011,11011101,
11000001,10101011,00100100,11100001,
00111111,01111111,11111111,10001001... etc

}
```

I thought of converting each number in the string to a floating point number and then extracting the binary representation; but, im not sure if that's efficient. I need to do this on a large scale with a .txt file with 200000-1400000 lines of XYZ data.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of this "conversion"? Why do you need it? What is the *real* and *actual* problem you need to solve?

Comment: I have a large txt file with XYZ coordinates. My goal is to take this data and process it and turn it into a BMP24 image. I have it working so far but it is way too slow. As of now i have a ifstream that reads each line one at a time and processes it. I was thinking I could use multithreading to speed up the process by converting it into an array of bytes and split it up into different domains and allocate a different section of the array of bytes to different threads.

Comment: well, start to NOT read line by line but read the document in chunks.
I don't think multiple threads will help you because my guess is you have I/O bottleneck

Comment: @CaseyPoon, if your program works correctly but takes too long, it might be better to ask a question at [the code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Make sure to read through their [how to ask page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) before you post though.

Comment: I apologize in in advance since I'm pretty new to programming. How should I resolve the I/O bottleneck? I thought about using a FILE* and converting that to an array of bytes but then the bytes will be encoded in ascii form. If i do that then i might have to parse through the entire file to convert it into floating point representation. Thanks for the input so far!

Comment: @RSahu I will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: If you do want to post about this on Code Review, make sure to include your actual code, otherwise it would be off-topic there.

Comment: I posted my code to codereview! Any criticism will be greatly appreciated
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201743/processing-xyz-data-from-large-txt-file-c

Comment: Unless you plan on reading the binary data file many times, the whole concept may be a waste of time (development and execution). For example, you read in a number, converting it to internal format, then write the number as internal format to another file, then read the internal format.    You may save some steps and read the text numbers into internal format and perform your numeric processing.  No need to write them to a binary file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
struct xyz{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

istream& operator >>(istream & is, xyz & v) {
    return is >> v.x >> v.y >> v.z;
}

std::ifstream f{"floats.txt"};

vector<xyz> floats;
copy(istream_iterator<xyz>{f}, {}, inserter(floats, end(floats)));
```